# Meu elemento html (h1) ignora a existência dos elementos acima dele

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho o seguinte código HTML que por alguma razão a tag `<h1 class="teste">` não está reconhecendo os elementos que estão acima dela e tenta ocupar o mesmo espaço do `header` na tela, acaba ficando se escondendo a baixo do header.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.open-nav').click(function() {
    $('.menu').toggleClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.teste {
  color: red;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

.content-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.open-nav {
  display: none;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

nav .list-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav .list-menu a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
}

nav .list-menu a:hover {
  color: grey;
}

nav .list-menu a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

nav .list-menu a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Futher Store</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header-side">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content-header">
        <img src="image/logotipo-futher.jpg" alt="logotipo-futher-urso" class="logotipo-futher">

        <button class="open-nav">
                        <span class="line line_1"></span>
                        <span class="line line_2"></span>
                        <span class="line line_3"></span>
                    </button>
        <nav class="menu">
          <ul class="list-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Medias</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <h1 class="teste">TESTANDO</h1>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sim, o position: fixed do header faz com que o espaço que ele ocuparia seja ignorado pelos demais elementos.

Answer (score 3):

você definiu a posição da tag header como fixa..

> ```
> header {
>     position: fixed;
>     width: 100%;
>     top: 0;
>     left: 0;
>     background-color: black;
>     border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
> }
> ```

defina um padding-top para sua classe teste que deve resolver

tipo:

```
 .teste {
     color: red;
     padding-top: 50px;
 }
```